Rigging a medal that swings along a ring
I am trying to rig this medal that is attached to a ring, which is attached to a ribbon. What i am trying to achieve is have the medal swing and move around when the body moves, as a real medal would do. When i move the empty, the medal will separate from the ring and not bounce or move in the way i want it to. I am sure i can use constraints and all, but i do not know how to use them properly. I tried location and rotation limit but it still behaves in the way i do not want it to.
What is the best way to achieve what i am trying to go for?
Thanks
https://www.mediafire.com/file/wnblfgytwfwbdx1/MEDAL+TS.blend/file



You could try it with Cloth simulation. Here the big cube is the body, the triangle is the cloth, the small cube is the medal. Give a Collision simulation to the big cube, parent the triangle to the big cube, give a Cloth simulation to the triangle with the top vertex as pin group, parent the small cube to the triangle (select the small cube, shift select the triangle, switch it to Edit mode, select its 3 vertices and CtrlP > Make Vertex Parent):

Make the triangle invisible for render, result:


Thank you! I have a follow up question, would it be wise to add some sort of cage for collision? For me, the medal clips to the body, and when i increase the distance, the medal does not lay flat against the body. Would a cage fix this? If so, where do i add it to, the medal its self, or around that area of the body specifically? Thanks
